# Content rating в Google play

Tags: android, google-play

Хочу уточнить по поводу `Content rating` при публикации приложения в `Google play`, я заполнила questionnaire в `Google play`, прошло уже больше 24-х часов, а мне все до сих пор пишет, что `Content rating` еще In progress. С предыдущими приложениями на это уходило 2-3 часа, не больше. В чем может быть проблема? `Google play` поменял время на проверку content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошло больше 36-ти часов, а `Content raiting` в `Google play`, так и не был посчитан, я нажала `Resume`, после этого нажала `Calculate raiting` и рейтинг сразу появился, скорее всего это было вызвано тем, что сначала я нажала `Save draft`, а не `Calculate raiting`.